# Where does Hironaka prove that (a_f) stratifications exist?

Tags: complex-geometry

In "Some remarks on relative monodromy" (MR0476739), Lê has an analytic function $f : X\to\mathbb{C}$ where $X$ is an analytic subset of an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^N.$ Lê claims that Hironaka proved that such an $X$ can be stratified in a way obeying Whitney's condition, Thom's condition (a_f), and such that $f^{-1}(0)$ is a union of stratum.

Massey seems to repeat the claim that Hironaka proved this possible in the third paragraph of the introduction to https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605369.pdf.

Both cite Hironaka's "Stratification and flatness" (MR0499286) as the reference. However, I cannot seem to find where in this paper Hironaka actually proves the stated fact!

The closest I can find is that, at the end of section 5, Hironaka gives a "Corollary 1" stating that you can find, for a *proper* map $f : X\to Y$ where $Y$ is a curve, a Whitney stratification of $X$ obeying Thom's condition $a_f.$ But it seems that Massey and Lê do not assume properness of there map, so I am not sure how this corollary can be applied.

**Question.** Where can I find a proof of the statement that Lê uses?